# Issue connecting to shared drive using drive mapping, external IP to Internal home server

Tags: network-shares

I have an issue mapping a drive from and external IP to a server on my internal network.

So I have a server (Windows 2012) 100 miles away from my house on its own network and I want to connect to a mapped drive on my internal network server (windows 2008). I have got MS SQL connecting from this external server using NAT, I can also access HTTP and FTP fine too in both directions. But I can’t for the life of me get to the mapped drive on the internal server and I’m pulling my hair out.

I have an EE bright box 2 router (also a TP Link router if I need to use something different I can use this) but to be fair the EE router has allowed me to get everything working so far inbound and outbound. I have several computers on my internal home network and they can all map to my internal servers shared drive. So I know internally mapping is working, It is just externally. Saying that I can’t map to the shared drive on the external server from my internal server either or any of my computer. I can connect to the external mapped drive from other external servers to the so I know that external server has the firewall set right. I can ping the servers from my internal to the external server and vice versa. I have AVG on both servers, windows firewalls and that’s it. I have disabled both of these.

What am I missing? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I am certain you have covered this already, but Mapping a network drive requires TCP ports 135, 139 and 445 along with UDP port 137 & 138 to be open - have you mapped those ports internal to external on your router(s)? - Port Forwarding I mean (was scrabbling there for the term!!)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Yes I have all those open. It is a very odd issue.

Comment: Odd doesn't begin to cover it.  I am somewhat of a network newbie, but still .... So, to clarify, you can ping the server upon which the share exists, but from "Network 1" cannot map a drive to the share that exists on "Network 2" ... do I have that right?  What is the actual error message?

Comment: Aaaaaand I'm wondering .... a VPN would solve this issue surely?
I was thinking perhaps https://openvpn.net/index.php/access-server/overview.html may work for you?